# How to find lowest value that is not null using Python in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I have four fields in my table, (A,B,C,D). The field type is double with some fields being NULL. I used min(A,B,C,D) to return the smallest value and it works well if there are no NULL value in any of the fields . What would be the easiest way to return the minimum value that is not NULL?

I think I found a very simple way: min(filter(None,[!A!,!B!,!C!,!D!]))

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using to do this?  Can you include the relevant snippet from your Python "code so far", please?  You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this which reads a little better IMO:

```
yourlist = [!A!,!B!,!C!,!D!]
min(x for x in yourlist if not x is None)
```